# Compare values from two time-stamps and calculate difference

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f73b4e2e7844308697dd149ecd3a7234)**

```
CREATE TABLE operations (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    time_stamp DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO operations
(time_stamp, product, quantity
)
VALUES 
("2020-01-01", "Product_A", "600"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_B", "400"),
("2020-01-01", "Product_C", "700"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_A", "300"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_B", "500"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_C", "900"),
("2020-03-15", "Product_D", "150");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
Product           2020-01-01       2020-03-15       difference
Product_A             600              300             -300
Product_B             400              500              100
Product_C             700              900              200 
Product_D               0              150              150
```

---

In the above result I want to display the `quantity` for each product per `time_stamp` and calcualte the `difference` between the `quantities` in the column `difference`.

So far I came up with something like this but could not make it work:

```
SELECT
product,
'2020-01-01' AS time_stamp_01,
'2020-01-15' AS time_stamp_02,
SUM(quantity) As quantity
FROM operations
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

Do you have any idea what I need to change in my query to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    product,
    sum(case when time_stamp = '2020-01-01' then quantity else 0 end) quanty_20200101,
    sum(case when time_stamp = '2020-03-15' then quantity else 0 end) quanty_20200315,
    sum(case when time_stamp = '2020-03-15' then quantity else -quantity end) diff
from operations 
where time_stamp in ('2020-01-01', '2020-03-15')
group by product
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=d52171d2e3f22828eef0fe00b8c43b4c